# Tariff wall to protect home industries

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence correct

> America has raised a tariff wall to protect home industries from foreign competition

**raise** means to end something. So the sentence means America has ended tariff barrier to protect home industries.

Doesn't it sound weird?

Comment: Where did you see the sentence? Since you've found one definition of "raise", have you looked at the other definitions?

Comment: It was a question in my grammar book and I was to fill in the appropriate preposition **from** in it

Comment: Is it possible that someone gave you a definition of [**raze**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raze), which means to totally destroy something?  It's pronounced the same as **raise** but has a totally different meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Raise" can mean "end something" but it's one of the least common definitions that is figuratively based on the main definition:

> **[raise](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/raise)**:
>     1. Lift or move to a higher position or level.
>         1.2 Construct or build (a structure)
>     2. Increase the amount, level, or strength of.

The sentence means that America (or, at least, a certain *American*) has *built* a tariff wall to "protect" the country.

"From" is the correct preposition to use with "protect".  For example:

> She was determined to **protect** her children **from** the evils of junk food.

Note that definition 2 can cause someone to *end* something, because the resulting situation is unacceptable or unsupportable.  For example:

> My landlord **raised** my rent, so I can't live in my apartment anymore.

In a very limited context a country or military can "raise" something like a siege, or an embargo, but most of the time these use the verb "lift" instead.

> The U.N. voted to temporarily **lift** the embargo of the embattled nation to allow shipments of food, clean water, and medical supplies.

Comment: I am assuming OP is referring to "[to end or suspend the operation or validity of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raise); _raise a siege_". And also _raise an embargo._

Comment: @EddieKal ah okay that makes sense, although it's odd to have focused on one of the lesser definitions. It's like thinking the verb "drive" is primarily related to golf.

Comment: @EddieKal synonymous with “lift a restriction” — this is an obscure meaning of “raise” or “lift.”

Comment: @whiskeychief "To lift a ban" is really common. I wouldn't call it obscure. Of course, "to raise a ban" is less common.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 'raise' necessarily means to end something. Nevertheless, you have picked out an oddity. Raising a wall makes it higher and more of an obstacle. Raising a barrier - think border crossing - means removing an obstacle.  Two synonyms are 'raising a tariff barrier' and 'raising a tariff wall'.  It is weird. There is no end to the oddities of the English language.